# Show drop down values of a select option based on another select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two dropdown select option. First is for select State and second is for select city. When any one select from state dropdown then related content should be shown on second select option (that will be related city.). I have some code, but it is not working.

```
   <div class="vali-form">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group2">

        <?php
   include("connection.php"); 
   $query1=mysql_query("select * from location_master where parent_id='0' ORDER BY location") or die (mysql_error());
        echo" <label class='control-label'>Select State</label>";
        echo" <select required name='selectstate'>";
        echo"<option>Select</option>";
        while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
        {   

            echo"<option value='".$row1['id']."'>".$row1['location']."</option>";
        }
        echo" </select>";
       ?> 

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group2"  id="response">

         <label class='control-label'>City:</label>
     <select>

            <?php
   if(isset($_POST["selectstate"])){
// Capture selected country
$selectstate = $_POST["selectstate"];

// Define country and city array
$query1=mysql_query("select * from location_master where id='$selectstate'") or die (mysql_error());

        $row1=mysql_fetch_array($query1);


    // Display city dropdown based on country name
   if($selectstate !== 'Select'){

    foreach($row1[$selectstate] as $value){
        echo "<option>". $value . "</option>";
    }

   } 
   }
   ?>

 </select>        

        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
```

jQuery-AJAX code is below.

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("select.selectstate").change(function(){
    var selectedstate = $(".selectstate option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "locpac.php",
        data: { selectstate : selectedstate } 
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#response").html(data);
    });
   });
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: If you're still using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API in 2018 then frankly there's no hope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has so many problems, hope this work

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group2">
    <?php
       include("connection.php"); 
       $query1=mysql_query("select * from location_master where parent_id='0' ORDER BY location") or die (mysql_error());
    ?>
    <label class='control-label'>Select State</label>";
    <select required name='selectstate' id="selectstate">
        <option>Select</option>
        <?php
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
            {   
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row1['id'];?>"><?php echo $row1['location'];?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group2">

           <label class='control-label'>City:</label>
           <select id="location"></select>        

        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#selectstate").change(function(){
             var selectedstate = $(this).val();
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "location.php",
                data: "selectstate="+selectedstate,
             }).done(function(data){
                 $("#location").html(data);
             });
          });
       });
   </script>
```

create a new page I call here 'location.php and put the below code there

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["selectstate"])){
    // Capture selected country
        $selectstate = $_POST["selectstate"];
        $query1=mysql_query("select * from location_master where id='$selectstate'") or die (mysql_error());


        if($selectstate !== 'Select'){

            while($value = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
                ?>
                   <option><?php $value['field-name'];?></option>
                <?php
            }

       } 
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.. still not working...May we connect with TEAMVIEWER?

Comment: yeh sure, give your id and password

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Any answer with mysql_* functions is a bad idea, especially when SQL injection is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select.selectstate").change(function(){...
```

You are trying to get select with class - "selectstate", but you haven`t it. You can try to add class to select:

```
echo" <select required name='selectstate' class='selectstate'>";
```

And ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "locpac.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: { selectstate : selectedstate } 
}).success(function(data){
    $("#response").html(data);
});
```

Comment: thank you for reply. But after adding class='selectstate', after selecting state, whole page ruined.

Comment: thank you for reply. But after adding class='selectstate', after selecting state, whole page ruined.

Comment: Above code is locpac.php file.  First mysql_query is for selecting STATE and another is for selecting CITY.

Comment: @user3526766 Try to add dataType: "html" inside your request block $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

There so many problems with your code so you can try the below one instead.

```
<?php
   include("connection.php"); 
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <label>State:</label><br/>
        <select name="selectstate" id="State-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getCity(this.value);">
        <option value="">Select State</option>
        <?php
        $query1=mysql_query("select * from location_master where parent_id='0' ORDER BY location") or die (mysql_error());
        while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
        {   

            echo"<option value='".$row1['id']."'>".$row1['location']."</option>";
        }

        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>City:</label><br/>
        <select name="City" id="response" class="demoInputBox">
        <option value="">Select City</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function getCity(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "locpac.php",
    data:'selectstate ='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#response").html(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

**and in `locpac.php` you can write the code only for the option instead of the complete dropdown.**

Comment: thank you for reply. But where I can write code for city list?

Comment: Above code is locpac.php file. First mysql_query is for selecting STATE and another is for selecting CITY.

Comment: There you want to check the city by the state, Then no need to write the data query for city name I suggest you trigger the state dropdown instead.when you select you to state it fills the city by ajax.